# creating Json from sqlite in Android

Tags: android, json, android-layout, android-listview

i want to have json file from my sqlite and save it in asset.myJson.json.
following is my codes,i want to see result in myJson.json. please help me how to import data to myJson.json.

```
private JSONArray jsongetResult(){
    SQLiteDatabase database = openOrCreateDatabase("ORCL", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT id,title,qty,price FROM CART;", null);

    JSONArray resultSet     = new JSONArray();

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {

        int totalColumn = cursor.getColumnCount();
        JSONObject rowObject = new JSONObject();

        for( int i=0 ;  i< totalColumn ; i++ )
        {
            if( cursor.getColumnName(i) != null )
            {

                try
                {

                    if( cursor.getString(i) != null )
                    {
                        Log.d("TAG_NAME", cursor.getString(i) );
                        rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i) ,  cursor.getString(i) );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rowObject.put( cursor.getColumnName(i) ,  "" );
                    }
                }
                catch( Exception e )
                {
                    Log.d("TAG_NAME", e.getMessage()  );
                }
            }

        }

        resultSet.put(rowObject);

    }
    cursor.close();
    Log.d("TAG_NAME", resultSet.toString() );
    return resultSet;

}
```

Comment: you want to write (resultSet) to file

Comment: are you getting your data in json object

Comment: @VishalMokal, my purpose is seeing that codes are correct or not.(converting sqlite to json). so i want to see result in myJson.json

Answer (score 9, accepted):

put this lines in your jsongetResult() function

`File f = new File("your  path");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f,true);
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);`

`pa.append(resultSet.toString());`

this is how  i have converted my data in json

```
public String getAllDataAndGenerateJSON() throws JSONException, FileNotFoundException {

    String query = "select " + NAME + "," + ADDRESS + "," + CITY + ","
            + CONTACTNO + "," + AVAILABLE + "," + CATEGORY
            + " from contact_list";
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery(query, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    JSONObject Root = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray ContactArray = new JSONArray();
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/ContactDetail.txt");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f,true);
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);


    int i = 0;
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {


            JSONObject contact = new JSONObject();
            try {
                contact.put("Name", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(NAME)));
                contact.put("Address", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ADDRESS)));
                contact.put("City", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CITY)));
                contact.put("ContactNumber", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CONTACTNO)));
                contact.put("Available", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(AVAILABLE)));
                contact.put("Category", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CATEGORY)));

                c.moveToNext();

                ContactArray.put(i, contact);
                i++;

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }
        Root.put("CONTACTDETAILS", ContactArray);
        ps.append(Root.toString());
        return Root.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the string concatenation operator to build my JSON (||) in the select clause in my raw query and it worked.

instead of

```
SELECT json_object('column1', column1, 'column2', column2) FROM table
```

use

```
SELECT "{" || "column1"  || ":" || column1 || || "," || "column2"  || ":" || column2 ||  "}" FROM table
```